# Command line wildcards

Tags: bash, wildcards

I have a directory X. Inside X there are many directories. Inside those there are - among other stuff - some .wav files. Using wildcards, how can I access all those .wav files? (so I can copy them to a single directory)

Comment: What version of `bash` ? Recent versions accept `**` to recurse in a file tree. Otherwise, use `find`

Comment: That's amazing feedback from all of you. Will look into the options and learn. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to copy all `*.wav` files into `folder`, you can do:

```
find . -name "*.wav" -exec cp {} folder \;
```

Comment: Notice that Linux has directories, not folders.

Answer (score 2):

If you want wildcards, recent versions of `bash` accepts `**` to recurse with `globstar` option (`shopt -s globstar`), see [Pattern Matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html) in `bash` then try

```
 ls **/*.wav
```

Otherwise, use more complex [expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html#Shell-Expansions) with [find(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html):

```
 ls $(find -name '*.wav')
```

adapt to your needs by mentioning *X* appropriately

See also [xargs(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html)